# Building a custom web part for site creation in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I got the task to create a custom web part for sharepoint server 2010 where a user enters details about a site. Fields are: title, description, dropdown with a list of site templates, listboxes with user groups and listboxes with site permissions (full access/contribute/read only). An administrator is supposed to be able to select one/many groups in one listbox and populate the permission listbox with these groups.

The webpart will then create a site with the specified template and the specified permissions. Is all this possible to achieve with a custom web part? I have worked with the provided SharePoint web services before (mostly Lists.asmx though) so I know how to use some of them. I know there is an Admin service but does it provide me with enough permission/parameters to set all these things?

This is my first custom web part and I have started to create a SharePoint 2010 Visual Web part in VS2010 and before I dig too much deeper I'd like to hear some opinions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can achieve all the things you have mentioned above via cutom webpart [Progrmatically creating Site](http://www.codedefiner.com/sp_createsite.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for Developing webparts for Sharepoint 2010

http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/developing-web-parts-for-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's all possible. And you don't even have to use SharePoint webservices. Since the webpart will run directly on SharePoint, you have access to all of SharePoint's server APIs. You can find full documentation for SharePoint APIs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556847.aspx